# How can I use zoo::rollapply to create a `rollscale` implementation?

Tags: r, zoo

I would like to implement the following `rollscale` function that scales (centers and normalizes i.e. subtract mu and divide by sigma) the dataset x but instead of doing it using a global `mu` and `sigma` they are computed within a rolling window on the seen data. I came out with the following but don't know how to define the function parameter on the third `rollapplyr` i.e. how do I know what the current position is?

```
library(zoo)
rollscale <- function(x, k) {
    mu <- rollapplyr(x, k, mean)
    sigma <- rollapplyr(x, k, sd)
    x <- rollapplyr(x, k, function(x) ???)              
}
```

The simple scale function would be:

```
scale <- function(x) {
    mu <- mean(x)
    sigma <- sd(x)
    x <- (x - mu)/sigma         
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `rollapplyr(x, k, scale)`?

Comment: pretty darn good idea! :D didn't think there is scale, how about if I just want to have say normalize by two times sigma? :) ok ok you gave me the answer. Please answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it is.  You have a `scale` function, and you want to apply it on a rolling basis.  This is exactly what `rollapply` does!

```
scale <- function(x) {
    mu <- mean(x)
    sigma <- sd(x)
    x <- (x - mu)/sigma         
}
scaled.data <- rollapplyr(Data, 5, scale)
```

Comment: Also note that there is already a `scale` function in R so you don't need to define it again.